# Label HTML service checkbox according to value returned from function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have succeeded in starting the html service and getting the check box itself to display. What I am stuck on is getting text to display next to the text box as a label, and I want that label text to be the return of a function in the .gs file.

The function starting the html service

```
function startHtml(){
//set up
  //can not define globally or script crashes
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //start html for selection
    var whichDevice = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('start_html')          
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(200);
    //main window title
    ui.showModalDialog(whichDevice, 'Setup Criteria');
}
```

The function returning something, a value of 1

```
function randomFunc () {
  return "1";
}
```

The html code. You can see 2 of my attempts to use a  element to get the return of randomFunc() to display with the checkbox. I have been able to get simple text to display for the  element, but I need to be function based.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <input id="testing" type="checkbox" />
      <script>
        google.script.run.randomFunc();
      </script>
    
      <label for="testing">
        <script>
        google.script.run.randomFunc();
        </script>
      </label>
   </head>
</html>
```

[image: image of the html service window]

Answer (score 1):

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```html
<input id="testing" type="checkbox" />
<label for="testing" id="label1"></label>
<script>
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    document.getElementById("label1").innerText = e;
  }).randomFunc();
</script>
```

- In this modification, when HTML is loaded, `randomFunc()` is run by `google.script.run`, and the returned value from `randomFunc()` is used with `document.getElementById("label1").innerText = e`.

#### Note:

- As another approach, how about using HTML template as follows? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) In this case, please modify as follows.

  - HTML

    ```
      <input id="testing" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="testing"><?= value ?></label>
    ```
  - Google Apps Script

    ```
      function startHtml() {
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        var whichDevice = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('start_html');
        whichDevice.value = randomFunc();
        var html = whichDevice.evaluate()
          .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
          .setWidth(400)
          .setHeight(200);
        ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Setup Criteria');
      }
    ```
- About `You can see 2 of my attempts to use a element to get the return of randomFunc() to display with the checkbox.`, I understood that you wanted to show the value from `randomFunc()` to `label` of the checkbox when the HTML is opened. If my understanding was not correct and you wanted to show the value when the checkbox is checked, how about the following modification? In this case, please modify your HTML as follows.

  ```
    <input id="testing" type="checkbox" onclick="main()" />
    <label for="testing" id="label1"></label>
    <script>
    function main() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
        document.getElementById("label1").innerText = e;
      }).randomFunc();
    }
    </script>
  ```

Comment: I do not want the value of randomFunc() to appear after the check box is checked, I want it to visible next to the check box the entire time

Comment: could you tell me more about how the statement with e works? what is the syntax with all the (), =>, and {}
What does it do and why use it?

I tried using it and it did not work

Comment: @Andrew M Thank you for replying. From `I do not want the value of randomFunc() to appear after the check box is checked, I want it to visible next to the check box the entire time`, I think that in this case, my 1st proposed modification shows your expected result. Can you test it?

Comment: @Andrew M About `what is the syntax with all the (), =>, and {} What does it do and why use it? I tried using it and it did not work`, unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand `I tried using it and it did not work`. But, `=>` is Arrow function expressions. I thought that this document is useful. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) In my proposed script, after `randomFunc()` is run, the value from `randomFunc()` is used as `e`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function startHtml() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2').setWidth(400).setHeight(200);
  ui.showModelessDialog(html, 'Setup Criteria');
}
function getLabel() {
  return {label:'ChickenTown'};
}
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
       <input id="testing" type="checkbox" /><label for="testing" id="boo" />
        <script>
          window.onload = () => {
            document.getElementById("testing").addEventListener("click",() => {
              google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler((obj)=>{
                document.getElementById("boo").innerHTML = obj.label;
              })
              .getLabel();
            })
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble following along because the way you format everything is so different from how I do it and I am pretty new to it. could you explain it in a little more detail please?

Comment: I have a single checkbox and a single event listener with an anonymous function that calls a server side function with google.script.run.getLabel() that returns an object that has a property name label that gets stuck into the innerHTML of an element whose id is boo.